# Configure path to PowerShell console in Cygwin Emacs

Tags: windows, powershell, emacs, cygwin

I have Emacs running via Cygwin istall. In Emacs I have installed (via `package-install`) `powershell` package; however, when I run `M-x powershell` I get the following error:

> Searching for program: no such file or directory, c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

The problem here is that instead of `c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` the path to `PowerShell.exe` should be `/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe`

My question is: how do I configure package `powershell` to point to the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the variable `powershell-location-of-exe`, either directly with `setq` in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq powershell-location-of-exe "/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe")
```

or through `M-x customize-option`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it. It handles different cygwin drive prefixes (I have mine set to / in /etc/fstab):

```lisp
(when (eq system-type 'cygwin)
  (setq powershell-location-of-exe
        (s-trim (shell-command-to-string "which powershell.exe"))))
```

`s-trim` is from the s.el library which is available on ELPA, you will need to add `(require 's)` at the top of your .emacs if you don't already have it. It is necessary because `which` seems to return a string with a trailing newline, though there is probably a built in Emacs function to get rid of that, I don't know it :-(